# Warning on setting variable in MYSQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am getting a deprecation error on the following query, and I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax.

```
SELECT case_id, start_date, end_date,
@calc_end_date:= COALESCE(actual_end_date, end_date, CURDATE()),
DATE_SUB(@calc_end_date,INTERVAL 5 day) AS ending_soon
FROM authorizations;
```

The query works, but I get the following warning:
`Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.`

I tried (leaving out part of the query for simplicity):

```
SELECT case_id, start_date, end_date,
(SELECT COALESCE(actual_end_date, end_date, CURDATE()) FROM authorizations INTO @calc_end_date)
FROM authorizations;
```

And:

```
SELECT case_id, start_date, end_date,
(SET calc_end_date = COALESCE(actual_end_date, end_date, CURDATE()))
FROM authorizations;
```

And both do not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The use variables embedded in queries has always been sketchy, so I won't miss them when they are gone. Session variables will still be there, and that's what the message is telling you. However, if your SELECT returns many rows, from which one do you want to perform the variable assignation?

Comment: @The Impaler I am using that later in the query, I just left it out for simplicity, I edited the query now.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me in MySQL 8.x. For example:

```
create table t (a int, b int);

insert into t (a, b) values (5, 3);

select a * b into @total from t;

select @total;
```

Result:

```
@total
------
    15
```

However, if your query produces more than a single row, the query crashes. For example:

```
create table t (a int, b int);

insert into t (a, b) values (5, 3);
insert into t (a, b) values (7, 2);

select a * b into @total from t;
Error: Result consisted of more than one row
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1172
```

This makes a lot of sense since a variable can only hold a single value.

Comment: Imapaler I understand what you are saying. The query I have now gets the value for each row, and I can then use it later, and even to compare in the next row. Is there no way to reproduce that in MTSQL 8.x?

Comment: The whole strategy of using variables to produce the result you want is being deprecated. I would suggest you ask a new question explaining the result you want, and we can help you writing a brand new query from scratch with newer, much better technologies.